# Google service JSON file

Tags: android, json, firebase, google-play-services

Is it a must to get different google service json file for each service? For example, i'm working on android application that requires Services from firebase and i had to download a google service file and then later i included Google Sign-in option to the app. Is it a must to download another Google service JSON file ?

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to do so? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @cricket_007 I haven't included the new file yet since it contains different values from the older one. The older one i included _firebase services_  and new one only _google sigin service_

Answer (score 2):

Your app needs just one google-services.json file. Each time you enable a service on firebase or google console, download a fresh version of google-services.json file and replace the old one with the new copy.

Comment: I did try to add fire-base services and downloaded a single google-service json file until later when i included google sign-in for android they proposed another google-service file with different values inside. So i'm a bit confused here do i have to include new values from the new file into older file ?  @AnkurAggarwal

Comment: @SharkesMonken Make sure that you are using the common username to sign into google and firebase dashboards. Also, make sure that you are referring to the same project. Then, activate all the services (whether on google console or firebase console). Finally download a single google-services.json file from either of the console and use that in your project

Comment: Piece of cake easier to digest now what you have just wrote. Thank you for clarifying that for me. @AnkurAggarwal